# If $N$ is a finitely generated $R-$module then...

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Show that $\left(\prod_\alpha M_\alpha\right)\otimes_R N\cong \prod_\alpha\left(M_\alpha\otimes_R N\right)$

I'd also like a counterexample where this isn't true for arbitrary $N$. I don't even really know how to start with this, this has come up in algebraic topology course and it's been quite a while since I done too much abstract algebra or tensors.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is each $M_{\alpha}$ an arbitrary $R$-module?

Comment: @SantanaAfton I believe so, but that has not been explicitly stated in the question I've been asked.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you define the tensor product this might be helpful.

Let $n_1,\ldots,n_\ell$ generate $N$.

It should be clear that an arbitrary element of $(\Pi_\alpha M_\alpha)\otimes_R N$ can be written as

$\sum_{i=1}^n(\prod_\alpha m_{\alpha,i})\otimes n_i,$

where $m_{\alpha,i}$ are some arbitrary element in $M_\alpha$. Similarly it should be clear that an arbitrary element in $\Pi_\alpha (M_\alpha\otimes_R N)$ can be written as

$\sum_{i=1}^n\Pi_\alpha (m_{\alpha,i}\otimes n_i).$

Note that the way to do this in general are far from unique, to reach these expressions simply split up arbitrary expressions and collect the terms involving a particular $n_i$.

At this point it should be clear what your isomorphism should be (send $\sum_{i=1}^n(\prod_\alpha m_{\alpha,i})\otimes n_i$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n\Pi_\alpha (m_{\alpha,i}\otimes n_i)$). What remains is to show that this map is well defined (this might be a bit technical) and that it is in fact an isomorphism (this should be easy). While I don't immediately see a super easy counterexample it should be clear that this "obvious" construction will not work when $N$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: How do you prove surjectivity? In that map, the component coming from $N$ in the image is identical in each product.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Do you disagree with the way I write an arbitrary element in the right hand side?

Comment: If we consider $(M_1\times M_2)\otimes N$, this map would take the element $(m_1, m_2)\otimes n_1$ to the element $(m_1\otimes n, m_2\otimes n)$ (correct me if I'm wrong). I was having trouble proving surjectivity of this map, as I was not sure how to map to a element of the form $(m_1\otimes n_1, m_2\otimes n_2)$.

Comment: I think you are right about how the map works, but surjectivity is still "easy". Something that maps to $(m_1\otimes n_1,m_2\otimes n_2)$ is $(m_1,0)\otimes n_1+(0,m_2)\otimes n_2$. Tensor products can be a bit annoying and I might have skipped too many steps :) but I don't think I made a mistake.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I wasn't implying you were wrong, only that I didn't see the surjectivity myself.